# Are all React components sent to the client browser in the response of first hit to the website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have built a website in React which has different components. I make those components visible/invisible based on the role of the logged-in user. Also, I have used react router. My doubt is are all of those components sent to the user (client browser) when the user hits the website first time itself (and then show/hide them as per user role and navigate across them using react router)? If yes, is it a good practice (performance and security wise), if not what is standard approach.

Comment: Unless you've implemented code splitting then yes, your app is essentially sent as a single bundle.

Comment: Yeah. React app is client side app. So if you want to keep data secure you need to have a backend. You can't deal that kind of a situation with just only React. Anyone can simple inspect and see what's going under the hood. You need to retrieve data from the backend. you can keep your sensitive data in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice send to user all in one bundle. For example admin panel (possibly has vulnerable code). You should use react lazy to send components only after login based on user role.
If we talk about performance it also the best split bundle to the chunks for fastest first load.